# How do i use a javascript variable within blade curly braces

Tags: javascript, arrays, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a video player site and i have a "next" button which should stop the video , change the src directing to the next video and play it using javascript but I cant get around using a javascript loop to change the src.

Heres my blade file

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<section class="player">
  <center>
    <video id="myvideo" class="playing-video" src="{{url('songs/'.$songs[0]->filename)}}" controls autoplay onended="nextVideo()">
    </video>
    <br>
    <button id="next" style="background-color: transparent;border: none;color: white;" onclick="nextVideo()" type="button">
    <h2><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i>Next</h2></button>
  </center>
</section>
```

and heres the javascript which is not working

```
var i = 0;
var myVideo = document.getElementById("myvideo");

function nextVideo() {
  i++;
  myVideo.setAttribute("src", "http://localhost/Laravel/anime/public/songs/" + {{ $songs[i] -> filename }});
  myVideo.load();
  myVideo.play();
}
```

I know I cant use a javascript variable inside the blade curly braces directly but I am out of ideas!

Answer (score 1):

Store the Laravel collection as a data point on the button:

```
<button id="next" data-songs="{{json_encode($songs)}}" ... etc />
```

Then pull the JS object out within the nextVideo() JS method and loop on it (all JS):

```
function nextVideo() {
    var songs = JSON.parse( //get the data from the #next button )
    //loop using the JS songs object instead of the blade {{}}
}
```

Comment: i am kinda new to json so could you plz give me the code or tell me how to fetch the data from the object ( $songs is an array of instances of Song model and required data is filename).   This would really help me out...(I dont know what to fill inside JSON.parse(...))

Answer (score 0):

Try using Toggle Button

```
  <button onclick="Toggle()">Next</button>

  <script>

  var i =0;

  function toggle(){
    i=++i;  // each time you press button the variable i increments value by one (inside brackets only)

    if(i===1){
        videoStop(); // Function to stop video
    }else if(i===2){
        videoNext(); // Create a function which will contain url of next video , autoplay functions
            i=0; // return i value to 0 and continue using the toggle button
    }
  }
 </script>
```